# Running server-side Powershell scripts via Java Applet?

Tags: java, powershell, applet, server-side

I'm looking to see if there's a formal/proper way to run a Powershell script on server-side from a client Java Applet?

Powershell offers some great stuff, and up until now I've been using just a PHP form to execute the scripts but it causes funny behaviour with the Applet (for example running the destroy() portion of the Applet).

Also, a return from the Powershell would be great to display in the Applet. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, use [System.Management.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.aspx) and [JNI4Net](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net) for bindings? Because interacting with `powershell.exe` via console redirection is error-prone.

More info: [A JSR223 implementation for Powershell, using JNI4Net for bindings](http://gitorious.ow2.org/+proactive-team/ow2-proactive/powershell-jsr223).